# How to set state while the react component is mounting?

Tags: asynchronous, reactjs

My component needs to display the current location. The call to get the geo-location is asynchronous. To display the coords as fast as possible I issue the call to the get the location when the component is created (in the ctor). However, when the async call finishes before the component is mounted I am getting an error:

`Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the  component.`

Whats the correct way to set the state while the component is mounting?

Comment: without concrete code it's hard to speculate, perhaps look at [react-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-promise)...

Comment: If it's async, then presumably you'll want to let the user know something is happening, like render a loading spinner. Knowing this is the case, make your ajax call in `componentDidMount`

Comment: Yeah, doing the call in `componentDidMount` did the trick.